# Prove $\log_a(b)$ is irrational given that $a, b$ are positive distinct primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, alternative-proof, proof-verification

I know this is a classical proof by contradiction exercise, and there are full solutions else where, doing a quick search I didn't find any, but I would approach this question like this:

Suppose $\log_a(b) = \dfrac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$. Then this implies $a^{\frac{p}{q}} = b$ which implies $a^p = b^q$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we know $a^p$ has a unique prime factorization and so does $b^q$. That means $a^p, b^q$ must have the same unique prime factorization. If $p,q > 0$ then $a|a^p$ but $a\not |b^q$ contradiction. Similar argument for if one of $p$ or $q$ less than $0$.

Would this be a correct proof for this question, are there other common different proofs?

Thoughts after seeing answers: My confusion for not being able to see the answer right away was because I thought $\frac{p}{q}$ could be negative, hence there is another possibility in the proof. But $\log_a(b) < 0$ implies $b < 1$ which is impossible since $b$ is a prime.

Comment: Yor last argument is a bit wrong. You have to change to if $k$ is some prime number such that $k/a$ it follows that $k/a^p$ so $k/b^q$ which in terms means $k/b$, which is contradiction with $(gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: You really should say only that since the prime $a$ divides the product $(b)(b)\cdots(b)$, then $a$ divides $b$, which forces $a=b$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, that makes a lot more sense, I over complicated it a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a^p=b^q$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic you have a contradiction simply because the left side has $a$ as its only prime factor and the right side has $b$ as its only prime factor.

Comment: My only confusion here was that $\frac{p}{q}$ might be a negative number, but I believe that is impossible since a,b are prime, that what you say obviously holds.

Comment: Just to correct my last comment, you are correct that $log_{a}b>0$, since $a,b>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct, but some of the wording is a bit awkward. It's probably better to say something like:

$a | a^p$, so $a | b^q$; hence $a$ is a prime divisor of $b^q$, and so by uniqueness of factorization, $a$ must also be a divisor of $b$. Since $a$ and $b$ are prime, $a = b$, contradicting that they are distinct.

Comment: I remember this kind of question in my undergrad. First we had to do this with log base 10 of 1000. That obviously works fine. Then with log base 3 of 5, it doesn't come our right (powers of 3 and of 5 never end in the same digit), which is then irrational. When you do the proof on both of these, you will understand the general proof as well as T.Bongers addition to your proof.