# Prove that $\log_9 15$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, rationality-testing

Im having trouble with the following proof... Ill post what I have completed so far..

> Prove that $\log_915$ is irrational.

Ill attempt by contradiction assuming $\log_915$ is rational.

So,

$\log_915 = \frac ab$

$15 = 9^{\frac ab}$

$15^b = 9^a$
   (This is where I'm getting stuck)

Any hints/tips/advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476064/prove-log-ab-is-irrational-given-that-a-b-are-positive-distinct-primes

Comment: We can set $5^b=3^{2a-b}$ , but $(3,5)=1$

Comment: $9^n$ does not divide 5

Answer (score 4):

$a$ and $b$ are positive integers. $15^b$ and $9^a$ are positive integers. $5$ definitely does not divide $9^a$, so what must $b$ be?

Answer (score 2):

Although people have hinted at it, you must use the fact that any integer $n > 1$ has a [unique prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).  In order for to obtain $9^a = 15^b$, we must have $3^{2a} = 3^b5^b$, or $3^{2a-b} = 5^b$.  But by unique factorization, no positive power of $3$ can equal a positive power of $5$.  Thus, $\log_9 15$ must be irrational.

[*Edited to account for the boundary case that $3^0 = 1 = 5^0$.*]

Comment: "no power of 3 can equal a power of 5" Hmmm... *almost* none, actually.

Comment: Hahaha, yes, OK.  I'll edit that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the base of logarithm to $3$, i.e. $\log_9{15}=\dfrac{\log_3{15}}{\log_3{9}}=\dfrac{1+\log_3{5}}{2}$.

Suppose the last expression is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\log_3{5}\in \mathbb{Q}$. 
Then $\exists (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}$ such that $3^a=5^b.$ But $5^b\equiv 0\quad\text{or}\quad5 \pmod{10}$ and $3^a\equiv 1,3,9,7\pmod{10}$. I think that here we get contradiction.

Comment: $5^b\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ can also happen, actually (and $5^b\equiv0\pmod{10}$ never happens).

Comment: Thanks a lot! the first case can happen iff $b=0$ but $b\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$15^b = 9^a$$

After this, you can write it as
\begin{align*}
\frac{15^b}{9^a} & = 1\\
\frac{3^b5^b}{3^{2a}} & = 1\\
\frac{5^b}{3^{2a-b}} & = 1
\end{align*}

To fulfill this equation, numerator should be equal to denominator but no power of $3$ and $5$ will be same because power of $3$ will end with $1$,$3$,$7$,$9$ and that of $5$ will end with $5$ only, so their power can only be $0$.

$2b=0$ and $2a-b=0$

so $b$ equals zero but it is denominator in our first assumption of rationality, which contradicts our assumption.
Therefore, $\log_9 15$ is irrational.

Comment: Are you sure that $15=3\cdot 4$ ?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, observe that $15^b = 3^b\color{red}{5}^b$.

Comment: Sorry i had the same question which i was solving but instead of 15 it had 12. absent mindedly i proved it here.

Comment: If you think you have fixed your solution, you should probably edit the solution, not provide the edit in a comment...